# Windows Media Foundation - Right speaker doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, audio, ms-media-foundation

I am using Windows Media Foundation C++ for playing audio and video files.
My application is pretty much based on the Media Foundation guide - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697062%28v=VS.85%29.aspx.

My problem is that when I play a media file, the audio is rendered only from the left speaker.

Some more info:

1. The problem happens for both Audio and Video files.
2. My topology is a classic Input-Node -> Transfer-Node -> Output-Node. 
   The audio stream looks okay in the output of the Output-Node (It's a float32 stream and it has no interleaving zeros for the right speaker).
3. The Transfer-Node in the topology is for a future equalizer, but currently it does nothing. Even if I remove it from the topology, the problem still occurs.

I suppose the problem might happen because of some misconfiguration of the Media Foundation, but I haven't found anything out of the order with respect to the Media Foundation Guide.

Any idea what might be the problem?
I would be happy to share relevant code samples or give any other relevant info about my implementation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like either your source node is providing a single channel data stream or the input media type for the output node is single channel.  If it's the latter case then the media session is injecting a transform that downmixes the input stream to single channel to conform with the media type.

I would check the media types of both nodes and see if this is the issue.

Comment: Hello Thomas,
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to retrieve the media type. I tried to use GetInputPrefType() but so far I couldn't get it to work, and I am not sure that's what you mean.

Comment: To get the actual media type for a node you have to get the node's underlying object. Since the issue is most likely with the source. I would probably check there first. To get the media type for the source use the stream descriptor from the IMFMediaSource.  Source->CreatePresentationDescriptor->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex->GetMediaTypeHandler->GetCurrentMediaType is the flow for how to do that. Code on how you build your topology would be useful for giving exact details if this isn't helpful.

Comment: I retrieved the media type as you suggested, and invoked GetMajorType() on the IMFMediaType object. The result "CLSID_WDM Streaming Standard Data Type Handler". Is that a correct media type for mp3 file?

Comment: Try calling GetUINT32 on the media type using the MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS key and see what you get.

Comment: I am getting 2 channels

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem.
It was a misuse of the waveOutSetVolume() function that muted my right speaker (I used it with value 0xFFFF instead of 0xFFFFFFFF).
Somehow I've missed in the multiple code reviews I was doing when debugging this issue :(
So not related to Media Foundation at all.